# Grails Many-To-Many and One-To-Many clash

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, entity-relationship, relationship

I have the following two domain classes,
User and Posts
And I have two relationships between them,
User has 1-to-many with Posts with back reference. 
User has many-to-many relationships with posts that he follows:
The relationships I've got are as follows:

```
User {
hasMany = [posts : Post, followingPosts: Post]
belongsTo = [Post] //For the many-to-many, this is the owner i'd like to have.

}

Post {
  hasMany = [followers: User]
  belongsTo = [owner: User] //For the 1-to-Many, this is my back-reference
}
```

Now I'm getting a clash with Grails, I tried solving it through mapping but with no success, this is the error I get :

```
    Domain classes [Post] and [User] cannot own each other in a many-to-many relationship. Both   contain belongsTo definitions that reference each other. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Anyone know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using **mappedBy**, like:

```
class User{

  static hasMany = [posts : Post, followingPosts: Post]
  static mappedBy = [posts : "user"]
}


class Post{  

  User user
  static hasMany = [followers: User]
  static belongsTo = User
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) for more info about the **mappedBy**.